# Dynamic Linq.Table<TEntity> possible?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables in a DB with very similar schemas that need to be queried in similar ways. I created a partial class for the linq entities, and then made the classes implement an interface, IEvent which defines all the properties with matching signatures that I need. All is good with that, I can cast my results to IQueryable and use the same code to work on data from more than one source. What I cannot figure out is a nice way to get the Table based on whatever "DataSource" (i.e. event table) is currently active, so currently I have this nasty switch statement that will need updating if another data source gets added and I don't like it one bit. Anyone got any smart ideas, it is late here and my brain is failing... :-S

The code goes something like this:

```
private IQueryable<IEvent> getEvents(IEnumerable<int> IDs)
        {
            var db = new EventDataContext();
            // activeDataSource is an enum defined elsewhere
            switch (activeDataSource)
            {
                case DataSource.Source1:
                    return db.Events1.Where(e => IDs.Contains(e.ID)).Cast<IEvent>();
                    break;
                case DataSource.Source2:
                    return db.Events2.Where(e => IDs.Contains(e.ID)).Cast<IEvent>();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest making the method generic and using [DataContext.GetTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx):

```
private IQueryable<IEvent> getEvents<T>(IEnumerable<int> IDs)
    where T : class, IEvent
{
    var db = new EventDataContext();
    return db.GetTable<T>.Where(e => IDs.Contains(e.ID)).Cast<IEvent>();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looked like just what I was looking for but when I tryed to implement it I got the following error in VS "T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'TEntity'". Constraining to a class like Event1 works, but that kind of defeats the purpose. :(

Comment: I added a class constraint to T. This means that T can be any class that implements IEvent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, this is all very handy stuff to know and strictly speaking you have answered my question so I am going to give you credit. I am still left with the problem of deciding what T should be in the first place. Say I want to pull the DataSource from a config file. I was avoiding it, but I am thinking reflection might be a better fit for this problem.

Comment: Hi,
I came up with what I think is a simpler solution to my problem. I created a view and used UNION on the (currently) two tables and added a Source column, dragged them onto the Linq designer and wired up the associations. Now I can query and filter based on the source and cast the results to my IEvent interface so the whole thing plugs in quite nicely. I have no requirement to update the data pulled from the view (famous last words...) so this approach looks good from where I am standing. 

Thanks for you time jrummell

Comment: Your welcome. If the data will never change, then a view would be the best solution.